# how to display widget for a certain time before displaying another one?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**i am trying to display a typing indicator before actually displaying the message, so i have coded the widget of the typing indicator and the widget of the actual reply, but i am having trouble showing the typing indicator first for 1.5 seconds then showing the actual message. I have tried the set state and timer but it works for one message only!**

```
bool _nextWidget = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); //when this route starts, it will execute this code
    Future.delayed(
        const Duration(
          seconds: 10,
          milliseconds: 500,
        ), () {
      //asynchronous delay
      if (this.mounted) {
        //checks if widget is still active and not disposed
        setState(() {
          //tells the widget builder to rebuild again because ui has updated
          _nextWidget = !_nextWidget;
          //update the variable declare this under your class so its accessible for both your widget build and initState which is located under widget build{}
        });
      }
    });
  }
Widget bot(String message, int data) {
    return _nextWidget
          ? ChatBubble(
              clipper: data == 1 ?  ChatBubbleClipper2(type: BubbleType.sendBubble) : ChatBubbleClipper2(type: BubbleType.receiverBubble),
              alignment: data == 1 ?  Alignment.bottomRight : Alignment.bottomLeft,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              backGroundColor: Colors.white,
              child: Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
                  ),
                  child: Text(message, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
              )) //the widget to be displayed after 1.5 secs
          : Container(
          alignment: data == 1 ?  Alignment.bottomRight : Alignment.bottomLeft,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: 75,
                maxHeight: 100
            ),
            child: JumpingDotsProgressIndicator(fontSize: 50.0, color:     Colors.white),
          ),
        );
  }
```

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: i am trying to display a widget for 1.5 seconds then display another widget, i want to repeat this process each time the user sends a message to the bot

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: i added the code, so what i want is to make the delay of the variable _nextWidget happen each time the user sends a message, with code above it works only once

Answer (score 0):

you can implement it this way

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool _nextWidget = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); //when this route starts, it will execute this code
    Future.delayed(
        const Duration(
          seconds: 1,
          milliseconds: 500,
        ), () {
      //asynchronous delay
      if (this.mounted) {
        //checks if widget is still active and not disposed
        setState(() {
          //tells the widget builder to rebuild again because ui has updated
          _nextWidget = true;
          //update the variable declare this under your class so its accessible for both your widget build and initState which is located under widget build{}
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: _nextWidget
          ? Container() //the widget to be displayed after 1.5 secs
          : Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

hope this is helpful!

Comment: this was very helpful thank you, but the code works only with the first message, when i try to send a second message it goes directly to the second widget